# What is the best and most precise data type for storing latitude longitude in iphone xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-location

I am building a geolocation based app and i want to know which data type is best for storing lat/long i am using doubleValue but i think we can be more precise like 10 decimal places .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`double` is the value used by the iOS itself. iOS uses `CLLocationDegrees` to represent lat/long values which is a *typedef* of *double*.

IMO, using `double`/`CLLocationDegrees` would be the best choice.

Comment: Why not use `CLLocationDegrees`?

Comment: `CLLocationDegrees` is just a typedef for double. But seeing the latest comment from `Dean` it would be beter to use the CLLocationDegrees

Comment: @deanWombourne, ;-) Of course. I have already mentioned that CLLocationDegrees is a typedef of double.

Comment: My point is that you _shouldn't care_ what it is - it might change in later versions of the SDK (OK, in this case pretty unlikely but you get my point!).

Comment: Alright. Anyway, I don't think there are chances that Apple unnecessarily change `CLLocationDegress` from `double` to some other type as double is more than enough to hold the lat/long degrees.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the definition of CLLocationCoordinate2D:

```
typedef struct {
    CLLocationDegrees latitude;
    CLLocationDegrees longitude;
} 
CLLocationCoordinate2D;
```

and then the location of CLLocationDegrees;

```
typedef double CLLocationDegrees;
```

we can see that the precision is given as double. Thus, you can't make it better than that.

Answer (score 3):

There's already an answer to that in the iOS SDK :)

Take a [look at CLLocationCoordinate2D](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationcoordinate2d) - it's used by CoreLocation to store it's lat/lngs using the CLLocationDegrees type. If that's the accuracy CoreLocation gives you then that's a accuarate as it's going to get!

Answer (score 2):

No it will not, because the lat/long `iOS` will use is also a double.

```
/*
 *  CLLocationDegrees
 *  
 *  Discussion:
 *    Type used to represent a latitude or longitude coordinate in degrees under the WGS 84 reference
 *    frame. The degree can be positive (North and East) or negative (South and West).  
 */
typedef double CLLocationDegrees;
```